# pydy.codegen.ode_function_generators - No module named pydy

Tags: python, sympy

use PyDy's ODE function generator to transform the symbolic equations into numerical functions:

as seen on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4piIKV4sDw&t=3313s&ab_channel=Enthought

```
from pydy.codegen.ode_function_generators import generate_ode_function


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-70a0eed55c8a> in <module>
----> 1 from pydy.codegen.ode_function_generators import generate_ode_function

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydy'
```

I have that module **Installed**, i don't even know where to begin with this error

Answer (score 0):

Ok so,

`from pydy.codegen.ode_function_generators import generate_ode_function`

has been depracated i'm trying to use. `Lambdify()` which i think will do the job

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify